# delete operation for a dynamical array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I'm implementing a dynamical array of integers in C . 
I have already implemented the create,insert , doubleSize / halfSize / which are making the size of the array double/half, and also a release function . I'm stuck with the implementation of the delete function , which should delete a value in the array , move the other so it's look like this value was never added , and half the size if no element would be gone. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct arr_st{
  int *arrInts;
  int size;
  int elements;
};

void create(struct arr_st *a);
void print(struct arr_st *a);
void insert(struct arr_st *a,int value);
void doubleSize(struct arr_st *a);
void release(struct arr_st *a);
void halfSize(struct arr_st *a);
void delete(struct arr_st *a,int value);

int main(){
  struct arr_st a;
  create(&a);
  print(&a);
  insert(&a,1);
  print(&a);
  insert(&a,2);
  insert(&a,3);
  print(&a);
  insert(&a,4);
  print(&a);
  insert(&a,5);
  print(&a);
  release(&a);
  return 0;
}

void create(struct arr_st *a){
  a->arrInts = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  a->size = 1;
  a->elements = 0;
}

void print(struct arr_st *a){
  printf("*******Arraystatus*******\n");
  printf("Size : %d\n",a->size);
  printf("Elements : %d\n",a->elements);
  printf("Values:\n");
  int i;
  for(i = 0 ; i < a->elements ; i++)
    printf("value[%d] = %d \n",i,a->arrInts[i]);

}

void doubleSize(struct arr_st *a){
  int n = a->size * 2;
  a->arrInts =(int *) realloc(a->arrInts,sizeof(int)*n);
  a->size = n;
}

void insert(struct arr_st *a,int value){
  int i = a->elements;
  if(a->size > i){
    a->arrInts[i] = value;
    a->elements+=1;
  }else{
    doubleSize(a);
    a->arrInts[i] = value;
    a->elements+=1;
  }
}

void release(struct arr_st *a){
  free(a->arrInts);
}

void halfSize(struct arr_st *a){
  if(a->elements == a->size / 2){
    a->arrInts =(int *) realloc(a->arrInts,a->size/2);
    a->size/=2;
  }
}

void delete(struct arr_st *a,int value){
  int i;
  for( i = 0 ; i < a->elements ; i++){
    if( a->arrInts[i] == value)
      break;
  }
  //last element
  if( i == a->elements - 1){
    free(&(a->arrInts[i]));
    a->elements-=1;
    halfSize(a);
  }else if( i == 0 ){ //first element



  }
}
```

How can I implement this delete function ?

Comment: To delete an item from an array, you can create a new array of size old-array - 1 and then add all the values in the first array while skipping the value you don't want and then assign the new array to the old array variable. So you're not _really_ deleting it but it's close enough

Comment: You can't delete an element from an array, you can only overwrite it.

Comment: Note that your use of `realloc()` is going to leak memory if `realloc()` fails. Not coincidentally, your code seems to assume `[m/re]alloc()` have infinite memory and address space available.

Comment: @EOF what is your suggestion ? I test the code with valgrind and there were no memory leaks .

Comment: @SHristoskov I'd *hope* there were no memory leaks, because then there would *also* presumably be NULL-dereferences, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David so i have to create a new struct arr_st , add all the values (skip the value i dont want) make the pointer of the previous array to point to the new array and then release the old one ?

Comment: @SHristoskov You don't have to create a new struct. You just need to create an array (of the same type as your old array) and then assign it to the array in the struct after you've added all the values to it

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value its' type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) when calling `realloc()` do not assign the returned value directly to the target pointer.  If the function fails, then such assignment would result in a memory leak.  Instead, assign to a temporary variable, perform the (!=NULL) check and if not NULL, then assign to the target pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the element you want to delete (or provide the index as an argument of the function), say that's the index i. Then you would want to move the element from location i+1 to the location i thus overwriting the element you are trying to delete. Then you would increase i and continue moving the elements one by one until you reach the end of the array. Afterwards you could reallocate the array to be 1 element shorter or check if current element number is n/2 and reallocate to half the size.

Other option is the already suggested solution to create a new shorter array and copy all the elements except the one you wish to delete, then change the pointer from the last array to this new one (and free the memory of the last array).

Comment: This sounds good ! But I only want to fix the size of the array with when the elements are  == size of the array/ 2

Comment: Then you would only do reallocation if the number of the elements after the process is, as you said, size of array/2. If that is not the case you only need to update the current number of elements (decrement it) and you are set.

Comment: so after the moving just check if this is true and if yes, call the halve function

Comment: Of course if you wish to go with the second option you can first check if the new array should be half the size of the current one or not, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Rasty Exactly.

Comment: can I use the memmove function to do this ?

Comment: Since memmove works with characters you would have to mess with data sizes there so I wouldn't go that way. My suggestion is to write your own function for doing that, it should be pretty short anyhow.

Comment: If you managed to complete the task do not forget to mark the answer that helped you as "answered" so other people can find it when looking for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int deleteArr(int arr[],int index) {
  int i=-1,j;
  while(index != ++i);
  for(j=i;j<5;j++) {
    arr[j]=arr[j+1];
  }
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}

int main() {
  int arr[5] = {10, 20, 34, 70, 50};
  deleteArr(arr,3);
}
```

This code showcast a small idea how it can be implemented. DeleteArr pass the array along with index of the element to be deleted.